# Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: vector-spaces

Using the Rank-Nullity Theorem, find the dimension and a basis for the
subspace W of  $Q_4[x]$ consisting of all the polynomials $\displaystyle a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4$
such that $\displaystyle a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 0$.

Need some direction on how to start this question. Have some idea if a matrix was used but not a polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Recall that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ is a basis for polynomials of degree at most $4$.

Then, a polynomial can be represented as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Can you write the condition as a matrix?

In other words, find a matrix $A$ so that
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a1+a2+a3+a4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then, you're searching for the kernel of $A$.

Comment: what will happen to the $x$ terms can i just leave them out

Comment: and i am not sure how to write the condition as a matrix